# Random walk rerouting issue using netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I created a small network using the following code and implemented a random walk algorithm. I used some nodes as targets, where the walker is initially placed on one-of node. I used a path (walker-own variable) list with the walker to save its location.

Question: How to prevent the walker to not come back towards those nodes which are already visited and listed in its memory(list). 
I'm new to Netlogo and unable to implement this logic.

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [location path]  
nodes-own [ target? visited? ] 

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  create-nodes 30 [ 
    set color blue 
    set target? false
    set visited? false
  ]
  ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
  repeat 500 [ layout ]
  ask nodes [ 
    setxy 0.95 * xcor 0.95 * ycor 
  ]
  ask n-of 5 nodes [
    set target? true
    set color white
  ]

  create-walkers 1 [
    set color red
    set location one-of nodes
    move-to location
    set path (list location path)
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 0.5 2 1
end

to go
  ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of location
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
    set path lput location
    ;; This gets turtles to ask their current location 
    ;; to set visited and target to true.
    ask location [
      set visited? true
      if target? = true [
        set color red
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ;; Check for target nodes that have NOT been visited. 
  ;; If there aren't any, stop the model.
  if not any? nodes with [ target? = true and visited? = false ] [
   print ("All target nodes have been visited.")
   stop
  ] 
  tick
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like `let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of location with [not visited]`. But, this will create an error if there are none. So try something like this.

```
to go
  ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask walkers [
    let candidate-locations ([link-neighbors] of location) with [not visited?]
    ifelse any? candidate-locations
    [ let new-location one-of candidate-locations
      move-to new-location
      set location new-location
      set path lput location
      ;; This gets turtles to ask their current location 
      ;; to set visited and target to true.
      ask location [
        set visited? true
        if target? = true [ set color red ]
      ]
    ]
    [;;whatever you want to do if all possible paths are blocked
    ]
  ]

  ;; Check for target nodes that have NOT been visited. 
  ;; If there aren't any, stop the model.
  if not any? nodes with [ target? = true and visited? = false ] [
   print ("All target nodes have been visited.")
   stop
  ] 
  tick
end
```

Comment: Dear sir, I tried the above logic, by using let candidate-locations [ link-neighbors ] of location with [ not visited? ], but it gives the error " WITH expected input to be an agentset but got the turtle (node 8) instead".

Comment: I want to use the path list instead of " with [ not visited?], can you guide me how to use it?... @JenB

Comment: I have updated the code. NetLogo was getting confused, thinking that the `with` was attached to `location`, instead of the neighbors. So I added brackets to clarify precedence. See the line `let candidate-locations ([link-neighbors] of location) with [not visited?]`

Comment: Hi Sir, Can you please guide me how to check is there any circle will be created by moving to selected node and how to avoid moving to that node...@JenB

Comment: This is a logic question, not a programming one. Why don't you simply set the `visited?` variable to `true` for the starting location in your `setup`